# Declaration of variable causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, typedef, variable-declaration

I don't understand the reason for a segmentation fault error in my program.
The code is available [here](https://github.com/Muffo/KinectGraffiti/blob/master/src/graffiti.c)

At line 29 I declare a `PclImage` variable, defined with typedef like an array of struct.
The definition of `PclImage` type is the following (from **src/libMyKinect.h** file):

```
typedef struct {
    int valid;
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char red;
} Point3d;

typedef Point3d PclImage[480][640];
```

The program works well, but when I declare a second `PclImage`, I get a segmentation fault as soon as I launch the program.

For example, if at line 30 of the first file I add `PclImage bgPcl;` the program immediately crashes.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you declare a `PclImage` as a local variable (on the stack), you are likely to get a segmentation fault due to a stack overflow.

`PclImage` is an array with 307,200 elements, each of which is (likely) about 20 bytes in size, so the whole array is something around 6MB in size.  It's highly unlikely that the stack is large enough to contain two of those arrays; it might not even be large enough to contain one (as a very general rule, it's usually safe on most desktop OSes to assume that you have at least 1MB of stack space available).

When you have such large objects, you should allocate them dynamically (using `malloc` and friends) or, if you aren't concerned with reentrancy, statically.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with James that allocating those large arrays on the stack is most likely the cause. However, each `PclImage` adds up to only about 6Meg each. Unless you are operating in a limited memory environment, this should be doable. I've allocated far larger arrays on the stack before. Even on embedded systems.

James' suggestion of using `malloc` probably will fix it (worth a try just to verify the issue). However, I find it a good policy to avoid dynamic allocation when possible. Possible alternatives to malloc would be to declare the arrays in external context, or to increase your thread's stack size. User-created processes and/or threads often have fairly small stacks allocated to them by default. It can be a fairly simple matter to find where that is set and give it a large enough stack for your needs.

For example, if this is run from a thread created with the Windows `CreateThread()` routine, the second parameter controls the stack size. If you default it with a `0` (as most folks do), it takes the default stack size. As near as I can tell, that's "only" 1 MB.

Comment: You drastically over estimate memory in an embedded system. Having more than 32K of RAM is huge . . . and I'm taking from the perspective of 2017. In 2010, feel 16K was the availability in parts where we splurged for RAM.

Comment: @iheanyi - As said in the comments, some devices are memory-limited, but I was talking from experience here, not speculation. Of course ymmv, but that doesn't mean every embedded developer is working on a system like the ones you work on.